# NHibernate: Is it okay to manipulate the repository directly from my entity classes?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, repository, repository-pattern

I have a custom repository implementation using NHibernate through Fluent NHibernate's AutoPersistenceModel.

I have a bunch of entity classes which I persist with this repository.

The question is, is it okay to put real business logic inside these entity classes?

Is it still okay if some of this business logic requires to manipulate the repository itself? (Eg. some methods would need to create some new entities, some of them need to update existing entities, etc.)

I know NHibernate has powerful persistence ignorance features, but I'm still not sure about this detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic w.r.t Entities should be restricted to it's "business domain". 
It is a very bad idea/design to update other entities / infrastructure within an entity.

i.e.

```
Order --> OrderLines
Order {OrderId, OrderDate, Customer, OrderLines, ...}
OrderLines {OrderLineId, Order, Item, Price, Quantity, Deliveries, DeliveredQuantity, ...}

OrderDelivery --> OrderDeliveryLines
OrderDelivery {OrderDeliveryId, Customer, DeliveryDate, ...}
OrderDeliveryLines {OrderDeliveryLineId, OrderDelivery, OrderLine, DeliveryQuantity, ....}
```

Where orderLine's delivered quantity is a summation of all deliveries made against it.

Thus in the case above it would be wrong to create/update a delivery via a Order (i.e. order process), Delivery's deliveryLine is to be made against a corresponding orderLine w.r.t delivered qty(within a delivery process).

When transactional boundaries are clearly defined, you will never require the process logic to creep into your "business domain"

http://domaindrivendesign.org/

Comment: This is awesome, but can't I use the same classes that I use as entities as my domain objects?

Comment: yes ofcourse you should, if one did not do that, then it would defeat the whole purpose of mapping business functions to a domain.

Comment: So, if my domain requires to manipulate the repository, and I want to use my domain objects as entities, then what?

Comment: I'm not sure i follow you, by your statement "domain requires to manipulate the repository and i want to use domain objects as entities", as stated previously **responsibility of repository is data access and persistence where required.** It would be best if you post actual code, then context would be more clear

Comment: There's not much more to tell about it. I have a bunch of classes which I want to use as **domain objects** and **entity classes** at the same time. I know what the responsibility of the repository is, and the question doesn't have much to do with it.

Comment: **You want use domain objects and entities at the same time !**, an entity is nothing but a representation of the domain model/business object or whatever, if by chance you are referring to a DTO w.r.t a entity, it still would not have anything to do with an repository, as one would need to convert the DTO to the relevant representation of the domain model/business object, which then would be persisted via a repository (provided you are using a repository pattern)

Comment: http://lostechies.com/joeocampo/2007/04/15/a-discussion-on-domain-driven-design-entities/

Comment: Seems that you don't understand the question. I'd hate to create separate DTOs and domain objects. Why can't I use the same classes for the two purposes?